# How can I add a namespace in C# Express 2008?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Right now everything falls in this namespace:

XXX.YYY.(varies)

It's an open source project and I'm refactoring it to suit our needs. That part works fine, but I need to add another namespace after YYY for organizational reasons. So every single class will read XXX.YYY.ZZZ.(varies) How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code file, just change it:

```
namespace XXX.YYY.ZZZ
{
    /* your types that go in that namespace */
}
```

(typically still only one class / etc per file)

If you are moving *all* of them, then find+replace may help (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>)

You should also be able to use the "class view" to help track them: View => Class View, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+h worked, I didn't want to break any code but I'll take it.

Comment: In addition, you can create folders to organize your namespaces if you want to. When you create a folders, VS puts the classes in that folder in  different namespaces, by default. You can always change it in the code, of course.